# How to read, write and list folders and files in google bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I would like to read/write files in Google Cloud Storage bucket with Python.

Suppose I have a folder in `gs://my_project/data`.

- How to list the folders and files in the above folder?
- How to read and write files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to perform these operations. The most common one is to use the native Google Cloud Storage API for [Python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

In particular, **step 0** to use this API is to set up authentication to GCP, which consists in setting up a service account, downloading its `json` credentials and set an environment variable pointing to it:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH-TO-JSON-CREDS]"`

---

#### 1. Listing files and folders

In GCS, [*there is no notion of a "directory"/"folder"*](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1216). There are only buckets and blobs/objects. Nevertheless, the `/` in blob names are usable to emulate a folder-like hierarchy.

To list blobs from `gs://my_project/data`:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('my_project')

blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='data/'))
```

---

#### 2. Reading and writing files

To read from the first blob listed in `gs://my_project/data`.

```
target_blob = blobs[0]

# read as string
read_output = target_blob.download_as_string()
```

To write to new blob, I have found no other way than to write to a local file and upload from file.

```
target_blob = bucket.blob('new_blob.txt')

local_tmp_path = 'tmp.txt'

# write string
with open(local_tmp_path, 'w') as f:
   f.write('Hello World')

with open(local_tmp_path, 'r') as f:
   target_blob.upload_from_file(f)
```

Comment: I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to `C:\temp\abc.json`. I got an error. `chan.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to my_project.` Is it due to my role of project editor instead of owner? How to solve this problem?

Comment: It is all about the permissions of the service account (not your personal permissions). The permissions of the service account can be set at the GCP service level. So I believe that for this project you would need GCS editor permission.

Comment: I cannot change the role. What should I do?

Comment: You need to ask a project admin to grant you the permissions

Comment: what is `blob.upload_from_file(f)` where does `blob` come from?

Comment: edited the code sample. It was supposed to be `target_blob.upload_from_file(f)`. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

In order to list/read files, the code that @syltruong suggested didn't work for me for some permission error. I had to change the code to

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('./path_to_json')
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucketname)
blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='data/'))
```

which worked fine.